# Two simultaneous experiments with blocking

Tags: experiment-design, blocking

Hey there I have a marketing campaign (catalogues to customers) and want to conduct two experiments simultaneously.

For the first experiment I want to try two different layouts for the catalogue.
Let's call the experiment C with + refers to new layout and - refers to standard layout. My target here might be the average profit or response rate.

At the same time, I want to test two postal service companies. Let's call this experiment PC and + refers to the delivery of the mailing by a new postal service company and - to the delivery by the company that is already in use (this company can ship to every customer). Here, I am interested in the percentage of succesfully delivered mailings or response rate after a certain, short period of time.

So, of course I could split my customer base randomly into 4 groups and conduct the experiments completely separately. Particularly, I am not considered in side effects.

Unfortunately, it is required, that roughly half of the customers shall take part in the layout test (C). Additionally, the test for PC shall also be conducted on as many customers as possible.

Here, one could use an orthogonal setup like

```
C | PC
------
+ | +
+ | -
- | +
- | -
```

right?

So where is the blocking?

There are two restrictions I need to consider/block:

Firstly, the new postal service company can only address roughly 70% of the customers, (this depends essentially on the region where those customers live in). Let's call this blocking variable P where + refers to customers that the new postal delivery company can ship to and - where the company can't

Secondly, there are two customer groups that receive catalogues of different length. The customers with that receive longer catalogues are considered to be "better" than the other catalogues. Let's call this blocking variable A, where + refers to the prime customers with longer catalogues, and - to the regular customers.

So, let us assume for the moment that P is not an issue (i.e. all customers can be adressed by both companies) and we block by variable A.

Then, an orthogonal design looks like this

```
A | C | PC
----------
+ | + | +
+ | + | -
+ | - | +
+ | - | -
- | + | +
- | + | -
- | - | +
- | - | -
```

right?

So the question is, how could I incorporate P?

For the test of PC, I am, by construction, restricted to the set where P = + (the set where both companies can ship to, remember that the old company can ship to every customer). If P = - I a test of PC does not make sense!
Hence, the layout given above, restricted to the customers where P=+ is, right?

However, when testing for C this approach leaves some customers not randomly out.

However, the left out customers will be associated with PC= - (they get their catalogues by the old postal service company). If I assign to those customers the treatment C randomly, I have also the second layout, only that the group sizes are shifted in comparison to the PC-test.

Would such a procedure be valid? If not, is there any setup to conduct both experiments simultaneously?
I apologize for the lengthy question. I hope the intention is clear now?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to work out exactly which comparisons you're interested in, so not sure I can give you a good answer, but in general I suspect this is a bad idea. Skewing the design seems likely to introduce confounds/variance that you may struggle to account for. I'd suggest you probably ought to either run two experiments, or create a full, orthogonal, design.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I addes some context. I thinkt there is a full, orthogonal design lurking here. Potentially, it might suffice to restrict to those data.

Comment: The absence of context was only really one cause of difficulty. I don't find the question as a whole particularly clear, concise or coherent. You may benefit from rewriting it from scratch in a more clear, structured fashion.

Comment: hey, i rephrased the question and wrote a book ;) I hope the structure is better and that my way of thinking becomes more clear

Comment: Could you not just only consider people in the areas that both companies can deliver to? Obviously that may potentially place a limitation on the extent to which you can generalise your findings, but consideration of the reasons why only those areas get delivery from both companies would reduce concerns.

Comment: hey, I think that's what I'm going to do. This will probably suffice for our needs. Additionally, I still may conduct the C experiment (or at least fetch the data) on the set where only one company can deliver to. At least I may see some associations for further analysis. Thanks for the comments!